# Why in some conditions an email sent with idSMTP doesn't go properly to new line?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I am sending a text only email using `TIdMessage` and `TIdSMTP`.

For the `Body` I use a simple concatenated string like

```
Body := SomeText + #13#10 +
          SomeOtherText + #13#10 +
          SomeMoreText + #13#10 +
          FinalText;
```

Anyway in the generated email some of the "`#13#10`" aren't ignored. I log the `Body` variable and I can see that the text goes to new line, anyway in the email this doesn't happen. The strange thing is that doesn't happen on every line but only on some lines.

Do you have an idea on why this happens? Can you suggest something to check for? Is there some possible confict between `#13#10` and an text email body in some conditions?

**UPDATE**

After more investigation (thanks to your comments) I realized it is an Outlook visualization problem, anyway the problem is still not clear to me.

This is the body of the email opened in NotePad++ (I opened the msg file saved from outlook) where I show also line breaks (you can see #13#10 as CR LF. I highlighted in red and green the 2 line breaks that are problematic in outlook (but you can see that in NP++ they look like all the other linebreaks):
[image: Email body in NotePad++]

The email in Outlook looks like this (please note that outlook says that the message has extra line breaks and that they hahve been removed, but he offers an option to restore them:
[image: EMail in Outlook displayin bad]]

After choosing that option the email is ok:
[image]

I don't understand why this happens only on some line breaks. Does this help you to understand the problem better?

Comment: Are you using the latest Indy version (10.5.8)?

Comment: you can use `IdMessage.ContentType := 'text/html'` and replace `#13#10` with `<br>`.

Comment: @mjn good point. I was sure to have 10.5.8 but on the build machine I still have the one that ships with Delphi 2009. I will upgrade now an try again.

Comment: Please show the actual generated email and point out what you think is wrong about it.

Comment: I confirm the problem is there also with 10.5.8. I updated my message please see latest part and see if thie can help.

Comment: I would need to see the raw email data that Indy generates/sends, not the data that Outlook interprets/saves. Use a packet sniffer such as Wireshark, or attach one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components to `TIdSMTP`, to capture that data. What you have described sounds like an Outlook issue, not an Indy issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using `IdMessage.NoEncode := True` so that the Body will not be [RCF 821](http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/smtp/rfc0821.txt) encoded.

Or better use modern encoding `IdMessage.ContentType := 'text/html'` and replace `#13#10` with `<br>`

**EDIT:**
This is an Outlook Express issue.

Look [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816) and [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/26037/how-does-outlook-identify-extra-line-breaks).
  A workaround would be to add 2 empty characters to the beginning of each line of text in order to make Outlook not remove the breaks.

---

Note that Microsoft support also suggests using HTML format as a possible workaround with Outlook Express:

> Method 2. **Use HTML or Rich Text format**
>   You can use HTML or Rich Text formats when you create new items. Or you can change existing posts to these formats.

Comment: This answer suggests some workarounds, but does not answer the question, which asked why the lines are sent incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: I'm well aware of that Rob. It might be Indy, It might be the mail client. I proposed an alternative :)

Comment: If possible i like to use `#13#10` because I want to display the message on a `TMemo` too, so I am interested in `NoEncode` option. Could you please tell me which are the advantages/disadvantages and which will be the encoding in that case?

Comment: no problem displaying it in the TMemo. simply assign `Memo.Text` to a variable `S` and change `#13#10` to `<br>` and send it.

Comment: Thanks kobib, yes I will go first for the 2 empty chars trick since I am close to release and the less changes the best, then I will go for your `<br>` suggestion + variable idea in next release.

Comment: The `TIdMessage.Body` and `TIdText.Body` properties are both `TStrings` objects, so it doesn't matter what line breaks you use in code. Assigning to the `TStrings.Text` property will split the lines automatically. Then Indy will send each line individually with a `CRLF` at the end, per RFC requirements. You can `Assign()` any `TStrings` object to the `TMemo.Lines` property without worrying about what kind of line breaks are used.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the email client stripping out some line breaks, if your ContentType is plain text.

Comment: you mean the mail client is reading my email non correctly, "mis-interpreting" the line breaks?

Comment: Yes I confirm, see my latest update to the question. But why?

Comment: See [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816) for info about Outlook and line breaks. It looks like there is an option in Outlook that is set by default. I haven't tried using rich-text format as Microsoft suggests. I ended up switching to html formatted mail messages, but that brings its own set of challenges when dealing with Outlook clients and junk filters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 95% of my customers use Outlook so I cannot say them, to change mail client, so I need to fix the problem. Thanks, i choose this as answer since it is the answer to the question (so it can help other Stack overflow users), but I will use kobib idea for fixing the problem.

Comment: that support ticket does not explain **WHY** Outlook decides to remove line breaks, though. Especially for plain text messages.

Comment: @Remy From what I've read on various sites MS did it as a way to make plain text emails flow more smoothly if written in text editors that add CR/LF to make lines wrap.